# Java: trash in input Stream

Tags: java, runtime

I worte a small java function that calls another Java program and displays its input.

```
private static void call() throws Exception 
{
    int  line;                             
    ///Other stuff here
    Process p2= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java SelfModifying");
    InputStream is = p2.getInputStream();
    //p.waitFor();
    while ((line = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println("result: " + line);
    }       
    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
}
```

The prorgam that gests called is supposed to return a single int value: '10'.
Instead, I get 4 lines:
result: 49
result: 48
result: 13
result: 10

Where do the three other values come from? They are deterministic but seem to come from the input. When I run the program on its own it does not return these 3 lines.

Comment: Why bother? Why not fire up a classloader, load the other main class and call `main` directly, via reflection? P.S. blindly turning the result of reading from an `InputStream` (a single byte) into a `String` is not going to yield anything useful whatsoever. You need to use an `InputStreamReader` with the correct encoding set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading individual bytes from the stream:

- 49 is ASCII `'1'`;
- 48 is ASCII `'0'`;
- 13 is ASCII `'\r'`;
- 10 is ASCII `'\n'`.

So the contents of the file is `10\r\n` (10, followed by a windows newline).

You should wrap `is` in a scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
```